# Hover element with negative translateZ in chrome

Tags: html, css

Im using following markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item1"></div>
    <div class="item2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    perspective: 800px;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.item1{
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, -100px);
}
.item2{
    transform: translate3d(50px, 50px, -200px);
}
```

And when hover some item, hovered element become body, not container. Why..?

http://jsfiddle.net/6mtzydha/

Comment: in firefox when you hover an item, container bg changes.

Comment: how about http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6mtzydha/2/

Comment: @web-tiki, a little hacky, http://jsfiddle.net/6mtzydha/3/ better this one then. but Im trying to make this without additional wrapper. funny thing - if set position absolute to container, it become to work as I expected http://jsfiddle.net/6mtzydha/5/, but height 100% to body and html elements breaks it again http://jsfiddle.net/6mtzydha/6/

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS, it will change the background of `item1` or `item2` when you `hover` them.

```
.container{
 position: relative;
 width: 250px;
 height: 250px;
 perspective: 800px;
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
}
.item1:hover, .item2:hover{
 background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.6);
}
.container div{
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100px;
}
.item1{
 background: orange;
 transform: translate3d(0, 0, -100px);
}
.item2{
 background: teal;
 transform: translate3d(50px, 50px, -200px);
}
```

Fiddle Link [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6mtzydha/1/)

Comment: hovered element is still body

Comment: You mean when you hover `item1` or `item2` then `container` background should change? @SakerONE

Comment: In that case you'll have to make use of 'jQuery' or `javascript`. @SakerONE